# spacing in bash output

Tags: linux, spacing

I've a script that gives the output of status of the many process (on or off).
How to align the process name and status in perfect columns..

RED=`tput setaf 1`
GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
COL=40
...
...
if /opt/rad/beh.sh status | grep "pid"
then
printf  "$i"  "$GREEN" $COL  "[UP]" "$NORMAL"
else
printf  `$i`  "$GREEN" $COL  "[UP]" "$NORMAL"
fi

here, 'i' represents the process name that is in the machine.. didn't write the full code here. just need the alignment part corrected. Could someone please help me with this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format the output of a bash command in neat columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462894/how-can-i-format-the-output-of-a-bash-command-in-neat-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did and it worked !

```
if /opt/rad/beh.sh status | grep "pid"
 then
 printf "\t\t%-46s %-s\n" $i "UP"
 else
 printf "\t\t%-46s %-s\n" $i "DOWN"
 fi
```