# Use column -t to print two bash arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I understand there are multiple ways to output pretty columns using while or for loops along with awk, echo, printf, etc. What I'm looking for is a simple intuitive way (not messy) to easily print columns using the [column(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) command and two bash arrays.

I have found the following Q&A: [How can I format the output of a bash command in neat columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462894/how-can-i-format-the-output-of-a-bash-command-in-neat-columns)

which states how to use `column` very clearly, but the question asks about a bash command and gives a single command/string as its example.

My scenario is - I have two bash arrays (`in_db` and `local`). `in_db[$i]` entries are `Y` or `N` if `local[$i]` entries are in my mysql db. I would like to have the entries of `in_db` array as the first column and entries of `local` array as the 2nd column. Both columns will have the same number of entries/rows. I don't want to print any output to files.

I have tried:

`column -x -s "**" -t <<< (echo ${in_db[@]}; echo ${local[@]})`

where the entries in `in_db` will have a `**` at the end of the string to delimit the end of that 1st column. My assumption of the -x flag in `column` is that it will print all `in_db` entries first in the first column (hence why I print in_db first). I understand that the above `column` command does not print to my liking and I'm obviously missing the explaination of description for the `-x` flag. I'm trying different scenarios and -flags to make it print correctly.

I have also tried, instead of using two separate arrays, to prepend the `local` array with the string from `in_db` in a loop:

```
i=0
local_count=${#local[@]}
while [ $i -lt $local_count ]; do
   q=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/my.cnf" mp3s \
      -e "select folder_location from folders where folder_location = \"${local[$i]}/\"" -s -N)
   if [[ -z $q ]]; then
      local[$i]="N**${local[$i]}"
   else local[$i]="Y**${local[$i]}"
   fi 
   i=$((i+1))
done

echo ${local[@]} | column -s "**" -t
```

This prints as one line:

`N    music/atmosphere-sad_clown_bad_dub_13-(rse0095)-bonus_dvd-2008-raceme N    music/blink-182 - California (2016) [V0] N    music/Vitalogy N    music/Pearl Jam - Ten (1991) [V0] N    music/Vs N    music/Pearl Jam - No Code N    music/Pearl Jam - Riot Act N    music/Pearl Jam - Transmission Impossible (Live) (2015) [MP3] N    music/Pearl Jam N    music/Binaural N    music/Yield N    music/Pearl Jam ~ Backspacer [V0]-2009 Y    music/Beastie Boys - The In Sound From Way Out! (V0) N    music/Beastie Boys - Licensed To Ill N    music/Paul's Boutique 20th Anniversary Remastered Edition [V0] Y    music/1992 - Check Your Head Y    music/Beastie Boys - Ill Communication N    music/Beastie Boys - Hello Nasty N    music/Beastie Boys - (2004) - To The 5 Boroughs [V0] N    music/Beastie Boys - The Mix-Up (2007) N    music/Highway 61 Revisited V0 Y    music/1997 - Live Between Us [V0] N    music/2006 - World Container [V0] N    music/The Tragically Hip - 2012 - Now For Plan A (MP3 V0) Y    music/Red Hot Chili Peppers - The Getaway (2016) [V0]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we have two arrays.  For example:

```
in_db=(Y N Y N)
local=(one two three four)
```

To print them out neatly in two columns:

```
$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${local[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${in_db[@]}")
one     Y
two     N
three   Y
four    N
```

As you can see, `column` is not really needed but we can use it if you like:

```
$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${local[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${in_db[@]}") | column -t
one    Y
two    N
three  Y
four   N
```

#### How it works

`paste` allows us to combine two or more files a line at a time.  By default, the lines are combined with tabs as the separator.

Since you want to combine arrays, not files, we have to convert the arrays into file-like objects.  We do that using bash's *process substitution* feature.  In bash, `<(...)` creates a file-like object.  The contents of the "file" are whatever the output is of the commands inside the parens.  In this case, we use `printf` to format each of the arrays as one item per line.